# ORA-27465: invalid value 1 for attribute ARGUMENT_POSITION

Tags: oracle, scheduler, jobs, dbms-scheduler

I have procedure like this inside a package

```
PROCEDURE prepBillInfoforAccrualIntr (p_date in date);
```

**-- created a program**

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_PROGRAM(PROGRAM_NAME        => 'MY_PROGRAM',
                                PROGRAM_TYPE        => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
                                PROGRAM_ACTION      => 'GENEVA_ADMIN.IPGTIBCOAPIS_LMS_GENERIC_FIXED.PREPBILLINFOFORACCRUALINTR',
                                NUMBER_OF_ARGUMENTS => 1,
                                ENABLED             => FALSE,
                                COMMENTS            => 'MY PROGRAM');
END;
```

**-- defined argument**

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.DEFINE_PROGRAM_ARGUMENT(PROGRAM_NAME      => 'MY_PROGRAM',
                                         ARGUMENT_NAME     => 'P_DATE',
                                         ARGUMENT_POSITION => 1,
                                         ARGUMENT_TYPE     => 'DATE',
                                         DEFAULT_VALUE     => '');
END;
```

**-- enabled**

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.ENABLE(NAME => 'MY_PROGRAM');
END;
```

**-- created a job**

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB(JOB_NAME   => 'MY_TEST_JOB',
                           -- PROGRAM_NAME => 'MY_PROGRAM',
                            JOB_TYPE   => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
                            JOB_ACTION => 'GENEVA_ADMIN.IPGTIBCOAPIS_LMS_GENERIC_FIXED.PREPBILLINFOFORACCRUALINTR',
                            START_DATE => SYSDATE,
                            AUTO_DROP  => TRUE,
                            COMMENTS   => 'MY NEW JOB');
END;
```

**-- and passing arguments**

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE(JOB_NAME          => 'MY_TEST_JOB',
                                        ARGUMENT_POSITION => 1,
                                        ARGUMENT_VALUE    => '06-JUL-2017');
END;
```

It is giving below error.

```
ORA-27465: invalid value 1 for attribute ARGUMENT_POSITION
```

I want to pass static date as `06-JUL-2017`. I also tried with

> dbms_scheduler.set_job_anydata_value

but getting same error.

Could you please help.

Thanks,

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.1.0.7.0 - 64bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sched.htm#i1000820), SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE only works for VARCHAR2 arguments. If you need to set a non-VARCHAR2 value (in your case a date), you have to use SET_JOB_ANYDATA_VALUE instead. I think this should work.

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_ANYDATA_VALUE(JOB_NAME          => 'MY_TEST_JOB',
          ARGUMENT_POSITION => 1,
          ARGUMENT_VALUE => SYS.ANYDATA.convertDate(TO_DATE('06-JUL-2017','DD-MON-YYYY')));
END;
```

Comment: Hi my friend, Thanks for your reply. But getting same error. : 
**
ORA-27465: invalid value 1 for attribute ARGUMENT_POSITION
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ISCHED", line 213
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER", line 697
ORA-06512: at line 2'
**

Answer (score 5):

I got where is the problem.

in `DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB` we need to pass `NUMBER_OF_ARGUMENTS` so that `DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_ANYDATA_VALUE` or `DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE` won't give error.

Thanks every one for supporting.

Answer (score 0):

The error also occurs when you add new arguments to the procedure AFTER you had created the job. Then you have to recreate the job in order to accept the new arguments.